# javascript button event dosent work correctly

Tags: javascript, listener

I have a simple html table and want to dynamically add rows to it. Some cells of the table are buttons for which I have set onclick events. inside the listener function I just log hello. the problem is that, when I push the button, it prints 123 on the console then the page and console are automatically refreshed.

here's my code:

```
let row= document.getElementById("table-body"); 
let cell = row.insertCell(0);
let serial = 123;
cell.innerHTML = "<button" + " onclick='removeServiceMap( " + serial + " )' " + ">" + "حذف" + "</button>";
```

and removeServiceMap function is as follow:

```
function removeServiceMap (serial) {
     console.log(serial);
}
```

does anybody know what's wrong with this code?

Comment: It cannot read property 'insertCell' because its ```null``` or ```0```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to make the elements using:

```js
const elm = document.createElement("tag");
```

then you can add an event listener to it using:

```js
elm.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.textContent);
});
```

If you want to delete the row, you can just select the parent and remove it.

```js
elm.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.parentElement.remove());
});
```

To add the element you made to the DOM, select an element and use appendChild();

```js
document.querySelector(selector).appendChild(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

> it prints 123 on the console then the page and console are automatically refreshed

Most probably, your table is inside a `form` element, hence the button acts as a `submit` button.

Could you please share the HTML code also? If would help people better understand your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly, that was the case!! thank you so much. You saved of hours! the html code is too long and I think wont help much.

Comment: Glad I could help!